# Installation failed on Gentelella admin template for Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php, gentelella

so i have an issue while installing Gentelella admin template for Yii2.

the command that i've tried is `composer require --prefer-dist yiister/yii2-gentelella "~1.0"`

but an installation failed occured with the messages like this:

- yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap 2.0.0 requires bower-asset/bootstrap 3.2.* | 3.1.* -> found bower-asset/bootstrap[v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.2.0] but the package is fixed to v5.3.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap[2.0.1, ..., 2.0.8] require bower-asset/bootstrap 3.3.* | 3.2.* | 3.1.* -> found bower-asset/bootstrap[v3.1.0, ..., v3.3.7] but the package is fixed to v5.3.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- Root composer.json requires yiister/yii2-gentelella ~1.0 -> satisfiable by yiister/yii2-gentelella[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.1].

Does anyone know how to fix/solve this? kindly help pls, thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that the package you try to install has seen the last updates in 2017. I doubt it will work with current versions of Yii or PHP

Comment: As @NicoHaase pointed out the Gentelella package is out-dated. It requires `yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap` with Bootstrap 3 but your project is already using `yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap5` package with Bootstrap 5. Probably best way to solve this issue is to give up on out-dated package and look for updated alternative.

Comment: @MichalHynčica and Nico thank you for the information, that's also what i thought but i didn't sure before. and yes maybe i will try another alternative package.